# Receiving 403 method not allowed from Spring Security

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm building an app with an AngularJS front end and Spring backend. I have everything setup for CSRF on both the front end and the backend and it was working fine until a change I made.

When I log into my app everything goes fine, I login at an endpoint I made at `/rest/user`. It's when I logout that the 403 error is thrown. I have Spring Security printing to a log file in debug mode and I see that it fails when it tries to validate the CSRF token. I'll go ahead and explain what I did that cause this to happen.

I'm serving the AngularJS app as static content from the Spring dispatcher servlet and I don't want Spring Security to secure that static content. I figure it's just more load on the server. So I've set the Spring Security Filter Chain entry point to be where my rest services are mapped to instead of the root of the app.

Here's the sections of my web.xml showing this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Security entry point -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Because of this change, I've had to map my logout url to `/rest/logout` instead of the normal `/logout` that spring security maps it to by default. Here's my security configuration showing this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
                            secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" requires-channel="https"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/"/>
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="gtBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

        <!-- CRSF FILTER CONFIG -->
        <custom-filter ref="csrfHeaderFilter" after="CSRF_FILTER"/>
        <csrf token-repository-ref="csrfTokenRepository" />

        <!-- LOGOUT CONFIG -->
        <logout logout-url="/rest/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

        <!--<session-management invalid-session-url="/">-->
            <!--<concurrency-control max-sessions="10" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />-->
        <!--</session-management>-->

    </http>

    <!--<beans:bean id="gtBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.security.GtBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">-->
        <!--<beans:property name="realmName" value="gravytrack" />-->
    <!--</beans:bean>-->

    <beans:bean id="csrfTokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository">
        <beans:property name="headerName" value="X-XSRF-TOKEN" />
    </beans:bean>


    <!--<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />-->

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <!--<password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>-->
            <!--<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"-->
                <!--users-by-username-query="SELECT email as username, password, enabled FROM user_account-->
                                            <!--WHERE email = ?" />-->
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin@admin.com" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I have a custom filter that you can see on this line of the security config:

```
<custom-filter ref="csrfHeaderFilter" after="CSRF_FILTER"/>
```

This is where I modify the returned cookie to take a CSRF token customized for Angular. Here's the `csrfHeaderFilter` class:

```
@Service("csrfHeaderFilter")
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());

        if (csrf != null) {
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
            String token = csrf.getToken();
            if (cookie==null || token!=null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I believe the problem has something to do with this line:

```
cookie.setPath("/");
```

I've had a similar problem to this before and I fixed it by changing the path to the path of my app. But right now the path of my app is the root of tomcat because of how I have setup tomcat. So instead of `https://localhost:8443/gravytrack` it's just `https://localhost:8443/`.

I've also tried changing the path to `/rest` (the entry point of my Spring Security) and this didn't help. What could be causing this 403 error?

Comment: Thanks Graham, i got this confiruration of spring seurity with angularJS form your post.